# Generar código (no solo las cabeceras) partiendo de UML

Tags: java, uml

Edito para explicar un poco más el proceso:

Buenas tardes. Estoy en un proyecto en el cual estamos intentando automatizar la generación de la mayor parte de código partiendo de un diagrama UML. Con esa base, la generación de cabeceras es automático, pero mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de generar todo el código de una función.

Por poner un ejemplo muy sencillo:

Desde UML se genera la siguiente función:

```
public int sumarDosNumeros(int num1, int num2) {
}
```

Pero sabemos que esa función siempre hará el mismo procedimiento: sumar num1 y num2:

```
public int sumarDosNumeros(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

En nuestro caso tenemos determinadas funciones que sabemos que siempre van a tener un mismo código, como el ejemplo anterior.

Siguiendo con el símil de operaciones matemáticas, podemos tener funciones de sumar, restar, multiplicar, dividir, raíz cuadrada, logaritmos... Todas esas funciones siempre tienen el mismo código, pero dependiendo de la aplicación puede que no las necesitemos todas: Podemos crear una aplicación sólo con operaciones básicas, otra con operaciones científicas, etc.

Estas diferentes aplicaciones tienen un UML en el cual se detallan qué funciones se requieren en cada caso. Si tenemos sólo 4 o 5 funciones no es problema, pero si tenemos más de 100 y queremos usar solo 10 de éstas, es lo que estamos intentando automatizar, que esas funciones se generen "por completo" y no solo la cabecera de las mismas.

Espero haberme explicado algo más detalladamente.

Muchas gracias!

Saludos!

Comment: Que herramienta estas usando para diagramar el uml??

Comment: De momento estamos probando el plugin "Papyrus" para Eclipse, ya que al estar empezando con el proyecto no tenemos una aplicación "definida". Dependiendo de hasta donde se pueda profundizar en el tema de la automatización miraremos cual nos va mejor, pero hasta entonces iremos probando varias opciones.

Answer (score 1):

Lamento decirte que no es tan facil como crees,
debido a que las herramientas de UML solo genera las relaciones entre clases y las clases con sus atributos y metodos, aunque es el trabajo del ingeniero de llenar esos metodos con el codigo y función respectivo (espero me entiendas).

Sino cualquier persona podria programar facilmente en una herramienta de UML, ademas, es mas facil hacer los procesos internos a crear todas las clases desde cero (creeeme que eso da mas dolor de cabeza :/), ademas puede ser que esa funcion aunque la conozcas como sumar numeros, alguien mas la use para otra cosa.

Te recomiendo una herramienta que se encarga de solo modelado UML (si es que te gusta esa parte), ademas de hacer diversos diagramas: 
http://staruml.io

Tiene plugins y hay diversos tutoriales de como usarla, espero te sirva mi respuesta :3.